# Show that anti-metric space can only have one point

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-writing

Let's define new object. Given $X$ a set:

Let **anti-metric** be defined as: $b: X\times X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

- $b(x,y)\ge 0, \thinspace \forall x,y \in X$
- $b(x,y)=0\Rightarrow x=y$
- $b(x,y) = b(y,x), \thinspace \forall x,y \in X$
- $b(x,z)\ge b(x,y)+b(y,z), \thinspace \forall x,y,z \in X$

Then we claim that $X$ can only contain at  most one point

I tried to show this by using let $X = \{x,y,z\}$, then suppose $x = z \neq y$, $b(x,z)\ge b(x,y)+b(y,z) \implies 0 \geq 2b(z,y)$ a contradiction.

But I am having trouble showing that $X \neq \{x,y\}$. Does anyone see how?

Comment: You have the right pieces together, you're just not thinking about them in the right way. Suppose you have at least two distinct points, then your argument shows that those two points are actually the same which is a contradiction.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I see. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that for any $x$ we have $b(x, x) \geq b(x, x) + b(x, x)$ by the second rule, and so $b(x, x) = 0$ for any $x$.

Now let $x\neq y$, so that $b(x, y) = c > 0$. Then by the second and last requirements, $0 = b(x,x) \geq b(x, y) + b(y, x) = 2b(x, y) = 2c > 0$, which is impossible.

Comment: The contrapositive of the second axiom states that $x\neq y \implies b(x,y) \neq 0$, and since $b(x, y) \geq 0$, this means that $b(x, y) > 0$ for $x\neq y$.

Comment: Also, it certainly does always hold, since $x=y$.

Comment: Right, my fault!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have two distinct points $x, y$, then you know that

$$0=b(x,x) \ge b(x, y) +b(y, x) = 2b(x,y)\ge0.$$

What does this tell you about $x, y$?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the contrapositive of the second claim is $(x \neq y) \Rightarrow b(x, y) \neq 0$.

Now assume for contradiction there exist $x, y \in X$ such that $x \neq y$, and let $b(x, y) = C > 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
b(x, x) & \geq b(x, y) + b(y, x) & = 2C \\
\geq b(x, y) + (b(y, x) + b(x, x)) \\
\geq 4 C .
\end{align*}

So $2C \geq 4C$, a contradiction.