# Why do we want norms to follow triangle inequality

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

What purpose does Triangle inequality serve while defining norms?

Is it important to render it as a distance metric?

What would happen if we let the condition loose?

Comment: Without the triangle inequality, good luck proving things like if $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$, then $x_n + y_n \to x + y$.

Comment: Another way of informally stating the triangle inequality is "the shortest distance between two points is a straight line".  As D_S points out, the concepts of limits and neighborhoods would be warped without it.

Comment: @fleablood: But a line makes sense in Euclidean space, but, how do you interpret  the inequality with lines in more general spaces?

Comment: @gary The "intuitive" structure of Euclidean space motivates how we choose to define other spaces.

Comment: @fleablood: I somewhat agree, but there are some pretty wild spaces out there where lines do not make sense, i.e., space is not convex. I got a cold shower in a class on Metric Geometry whereoften  the only structure present was just the metric, one gets spoiled when working in Euclidean space having so many nice properties.

Comment: Isn't this question too open? What does OP mean by what would happen? A lot of things would happen. In fact an infinite number of results would fail. This question doesn't mean anything. A more reasonable question would be to choose one specific aspect of a normed vector space and ask what would happen if we remove the triangle inequality in the definition of a norm. These spaces have been studied and named, i.e. quasi-normed spaces and semi-metric spaces.

Comment: Why do we want norm at all?    If yes can answer this question you answer your question too.

Comment: Lines?? Lines aren't very important.  I was thinking of distances.  You won't be able to determine that points in a neighborhood close to the center point are actually close to each other.  Can't define limits or continuity if we can't assume being close to a mutual point makes points close to each other and that's a huge limitation.

Comment: I usually think of the triangle inequality as a way of saying that "you can't get from point A to point B any faster by taking some sort of detour through C"

Comment: Culdevu exactly!  Furthermore you can't have places far apart if the are mutually close.  If a and b are both within an epsilon of c, a and b can't be a huge distance away from each other.

Comment: If you drop the triangle inequality the "open balls" may fail to be a base for a topology.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet well , If there's a Topology  !

Comment: The story is told of a Ph.D. thesis written on the subject of [antimetric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869120/show-that-anti-metric-space-can-only-have-one-point).

Answer (score 13):

Properties whose proofs rely on the triangle inequality include:

- A ball is convex.
- Vector addition is continuous.

Comment: @Chickenmancer  How is this _not_ addressing the question?  OP asked what would happen if we relaxed this, and Andrew addressed that

Answer (score 8):

If one defines a map $\|{\cdot} \| : V\to \Bbb{R}$ that satisfies all of the conditions of being a norm, but we are less strict with the traditional triangle inequality; for example

$$\|x+y\|\leq K(\|x\|+\|y\|) $$
for some fixed $K>0,$ then we call this a **quasinorm.** There is much to consider of such a definition, see: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1945-51-01/S0002-9904-1945-08273-1/S0002-9904-1945-08273-1.pdf

When $K$ is not fixed there isn't clear answer as to what your function **is actually telling you about $V$**. What is desirable about the triangle inequality is that it furnishes us with a metric, that is, if you define $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|,$ then you establish $(V,d)$ as a metric space as you have already pointed out.

Others have pointed out various other conditions, all of which are contingent on the topology endowed by the metric defined by the norm. So what happens in the end when you define a map which ignores the triangle inequality, you ignore the metric topology, and in particular, you ignore any geometric aspects of your vector space which may be of use. Moreover, metric spaces can greatly reduce the difficulty of many arguments, and may even allow for analysis (depending on the field $V$ is defined over).